# Word MailMerge with VBA Macro extremely Slow and can't control-break

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I got this code off the internet and it works however, it's extremely slow and I can't interrupt it with CTRL-C.  I'm just learning VBA and seek expertise in resolving issue.  I run this from Word/Mailings/Macro

In regard to slowness: The screen repaints on every record. It doesn't update with current record, just repaints.  I tried inserting Application.ScreenUpdating = False but it didn't stop.  Not sure I have it in right place.  When I say slow I mean incredibly slow.  I successfully tried similar code from within excel and it exported 50,000 records in 12 hours whereas this thing has run about 16 hours already and has yet to reach 15,000 records.

The other thing is I can't stop it once it's running short of killing it with Task Manager.  In fact I can't even get to the code window once it starts and doesn't respond to cursor clicks on anything.  I can't even minimize the screen.

This code has a MasterDocument that the user creates and within the VBA it creates another document or SingleDoc that it exports.  Can't help but wonder if this also contributes to slowness but wouldn't know how to alter so just the MasterDoc updates are exports which would be more like my Excel script that just updates the design sheet and exports.

Any suggestions as to how to improve efficiency and/or speed is appreciated.

```
Sub MailMergeToPdfBasic()                                                        

Dim masterDoc As Document, singleDoc As Document, lastRecordNum As Long   
Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument                                               

masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord                   
lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord                 

masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False            

Do While lastRecordNum > 0                                                   
    masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument                    
    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord             
    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord               
    masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False                                        
    Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument  
                                     
    singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF                                      
    singleDoc.Close False                                                    
    If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then     
        lastRecordNum = 0                                                    
    Else
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord           
    End If

Loop                                                                         

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Adding a line with the command "DoEvents" in your Do loop *may* help you interrupt the VBA processing. As for performance, difficult to tell without being able to replicate, but I would look for: "complication" of any kind in your mail merge main document (e.g. is it a simple plain text document, or does it pull in lots of graphics/images?), is your data source being accessed via OLEDB (usually better) or is it e.g. a Word document (usually worse). Without checking, not obvious why your .Screenupdating assignments are not helping, but minimising the relevant windows during the merge mayhelp.

Comment: @jonsson Thanks for the interrupt tip.  It's a simple document with 11 fields.  dates,  integer, 6varchar < 30, and 1 long text.  Since the excel macro doesn't do this for exact same data and fields I can't help but think it's the VBA code for MailMerge or Word itself.  By the way, the Application.ScreenUpdating = False  isn't working and no response on minimize click.   I open an app to cover.   I wonder if it's being overridden when the macro creates a temp document.   Can't the PDF be created from the Master Document? If so how to fix?

Comment: I've been away, but I fInally managed to set up my own test here using your code, with a very simple mailmerge main document and an OLE DB data source. Just very, very slow, c. 10 to 13 seconds per document, regardless of whether I used .saveasfixedformat or .saveas2, and in the latter case, regardless of whether I was saving as .pdf or .docx. I don't remember seeing performance that poor with .docx but it is a while since I tested on the current version of Office 365. I'm going to retest on an older version if I can.

Comment: I started with Office 365 and then tried Word 2021 on my personal machine.  My local machine was a little faster but nowhere near the speed of an Excel macro doing basically same thing but not same code. I attributed the performance improvement to my local machine with more horsepower.  I might note the first 10,000 records or so went pretty fast (several docs. per second) and then began crawling like you describe.

Comment: See, for example *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: @macropod That's a good article yet I see no correlation to this issue.  In browsing the code the only difference I see is FOR loop versus WHILE loop.  Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: @user3525187 Well, amongst other things, you won't get the constant screen updating. And, yes, the For loop is more efficient. The save code is more efficient, too. You should also ensure your mailmerge uses the standard OLEDB connection method rather than the older DDE method. OLEDB is much more efficient - and flexible. If you're presently using DDE, though, you may need to apply some field formatting switches in the mailmerge main document to get the desired output formats once you switch to OLEDB.